# Declaring templated member reference to templated member array of another class

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, static-variables

Template `class OtherClass` has a template member that is a reference to template `class BitReferenceHost`'s template member, which is a `std::array` constructed using `make_integer_sequence` and two templated member methods of `BitReferenceHost`.

I have correctly declared `XBitMask` in `BitReferenceHost`, but I am having trouble in `OtherClass` where it uses a reference to the static member of `BitReferenceHost`.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <limits>
#include <functional>

template <typename Aspect>
class BitReferenceHost {
    public:

    template <uint8_t BitCount, uint64_t... Indexes>
    static constexpr const std::array<uint64_t, sizeof...(Indexes)>
    initializeXBitMasks(const std::integer_sequence<uint64_t, Indexes...>&) {
        return { initializeXBitMasks<BitCount>( Indexes )... };
    }

    template<
        uint8_t   BitCount,
        uint8_t   ShiftDistance = BitCount + 1,
        uint64_t  BaseMask      = (1ULL << ShiftDistance) - 1
    > static constexpr const uint64_t initializeXBitMasks(
        const uint64_t& mask_index
    ) {
        return BaseMask << (BitCount * mask_index);
    }

    template <
        uint8_t   BitCount,
        typename  MaskInt = uint64_t,
        uint8_t   Count   = std::numeric_limits<MaskInt>::digits / BitCount
    > static constexpr const std::array <MaskInt, Count>
    XBitMask = initializeXBitMasks<BitCount>(
        std::make_integer_sequence<MaskInt, Count>{}
    );

};

template <typename Aspect>
template <uint8_t  BitCount,
  typename MaskInt,
  uint8_t  Count
> const std::array<MaskInt, Count> BitReferenceHost<Aspect>::XBitMask;

template <typename Aspect, typename... Args>
class OtherClass {
    public:
    using ReferenceHost = ::BitReferenceHost<Aspect>;

    template <uint8_t  BitMaskBitCount>
    static constexpr const auto& XBitMask =
            ReferenceHost::template XBitMask<BitMaskBitCount>;
};

template <typename Aspect, typename... Args>
template <uint8_t  BitMaskBitCount>
const auto& OtherClass<Aspect, Args...>::XBitMask;
```

Update (Solution):

Working code per answer provided by max66:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <limits>
#include <functional>

template <typename  Aspect> class BitReferenceHost {
  template <uint8_t BitCount, uint64_t... Indexes>
  static constexpr const std::array<uint64_t, sizeof...(Indexes)>
  initializeXBitMasks( const std::integer_sequence<uint64_t, Indexes...>& )
  {
    return { { initializeXBitMasks<BitCount>( Indexes )... } };
  }
  template
  <
    uint8_t   BitCount,
    uint64_t  BaseMask      = (1ULL << BitCount) - 1
  >
  static constexpr uint64_t
  initializeXBitMasks(
    const uint64_t&  mask_index )
  {
    return BaseMask << (BitCount * mask_index);
  }

   public:
  template
  <
    uint8_t   BitCount,
    typename  MaskInt = uint64_t,
    uint8_t   Count   = std::numeric_limits<MaskInt>::digits / BitCount
  >
  static constexpr const std::array<MaskInt,Count>
  XBitMask = initializeXBitMasks<BitCount>( std::make_integer_sequence<MaskInt, Count>{} );
};

template<typename  Aspect>
template
<uint8_t BitCount, typename MaskInt, uint8_t Count>
const std::array<MaskInt, Count>
BitReferenceHost<Aspect>::XBitMask;

template <typename Aspect, typename... Args> class OtherClass
{
  using ReferenceHost = ::BitReferenceHost<Aspect>;
   public:
  template <uint8_t  BitMaskBitCount> static constexpr const decltype(ReferenceHost::template XBitMask<BitMaskBitCount>)&
  XBitMask = ReferenceHost::template XBitMask<BitMaskBitCount>;
};

template <typename Aspect, typename... Args>
template <uint8_t  BitMaskBitCount>
constexpr const decltype(OtherClass<Aspect, Args...>::ReferenceHost::template XBitMask<BitMaskBitCount>)&
OtherClass
<Aspect, Args...>::XBitMask;

int main()
{
  uint64_t test_int = OtherClass<uint64_t>::XBitMask<1>[0];

  std::cout << test_int << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert but... I have problem compiling your code because (if I understand well the error message from clang) the `auto` type in

```
template <typename Aspect, typename... Args>
template <uint8_t  BitMaskBitCount>
const auto& OtherClass<Aspect, Args...>::XBitMask;
```

can't be deduced because there isn't a initialization value.

I compile in two ways

(1) deleting the declaration outside the class definition

```
template <typename Aspect, typename... Args>
class OtherClass {
    using ReferenceHost = ::BitReferenceHost<Aspect>;

    template <uint8_t  BitMaskBitCount>
    static constexpr const auto& XBitMask =
            ReferenceHost::template XBitMask<BitMaskBitCount>;
};

//template <typename Aspect, typename... Args>
//template <uint8_t  BitMaskBitCount>
//const auto& OtherClass<Aspect, Args...>::XBitMask;
```

(2) avoiding `auto` for the type (and usign a `using` defined type to semplify)

```
template <typename Aspect, typename... Args>
class OtherClass {
    using ReferenceHost = ::BitReferenceHost<Aspect>;
    template <uint8_t  BitMaskBitCount>
    using xbit_t        = decltype(ReferenceHost::template XBitMask<BitMaskBitCount>); 

    template <uint8_t  BitMaskBitCount>
    static constexpr xbit_t<BitMaskBitCount> & XBitMask =
            ReferenceHost::template XBitMask<BitMaskBitCount>;
};

template <typename Aspect, typename... Args>
template <uint8_t  BitMaskBitCount>
constexpr OtherClass<Aspect, Args...>::xbit_t<BitMaskBitCount> & 
   OtherClass<Aspect, Args...>::XBitMask;
```

Comment: All examples I have found for #2 result in clang and gcc segfaulting - http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/YwxOasovCcbkqGjL

Comment: And #1 means that it's not accessible outside the class.

Comment: @Asher - sorry but the problem "it's not accessible outside the class" is related to the fact that `XBitMask` is defined `private` (defaul in a class) in `OtherClass` and in `BitReferenceHost`; try defining they as `public`.

Comment: Err that was inadvertent and is unrelated (although correct - code updated to reflect). A declaration is still needed once public.

Comment: @Asher - I'm surprised by the gcc segfaulting but it seems a gcc problem; if you trasform `XBitMask` as `public` and a double brackets returning from `initializeXBitMasks()` (I mean: `return { { initializeXBitMasks<BitCount>( Indexes )... } };` instead of `return { initializeXBitMasks<BitCount>( Indexes )... };`, well... with clang should compile (p.s.: the single bracket give only a warning)

Comment: Would you mind linking the entire code text in an online ide such as ideone or melpon? Or posting it as a single code block here?

Comment: @Asher - I'm a little muddler with this sort of things but... I've tried [in this page](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2Y95uXAMNnvsq42l)